# How to redirect output to file, not creating it if it does not exist?

Tags: shell

I need to redirect output to a file with `>` in shell, but the file should not be created if it does not already exist. How to achieve this?

I tried by creating a symlink to the file and redirecting to the symlink, but unfortunately the file is created anyway, if it does not already exist.

Probably I need to redirect to a separate program which does the checking, instead of shell. Anybody knows a program that can do this?

**NOTE** I need it to work in OpenWrt (i.e., with `busybox`'s versions of utilities).

Comment: What do you want to happen to the redirected output if the file is not created? Just drop it to /dev/null?  Also, this is probably off-topic for StackOverflow. Might be a better fit for superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I don't know of any shell that supports this. Have you considered just manually checking if the file exists first?

Comment: @thatotherguy I need to do this in one command to avoid race condition

Comment: @ghoti I want the shell command to fail with error if file does not already exist

Comment: You could do `yourcommand | dd conv=nocreat of=yourfile` to check+open  atomically, but unlike a failed redirection, the command would be started and run for a bit before it discovers this.

Comment: @thatotherguy Your idea is great, but unfortunately it does not work with `busybox`'s   `dd`: `dd: invalid argument 'nocreat' to 'conv'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
/* Printer device file must not be created if it does not
already exist. This is similar to `cat >', but open()
syscall is without O_CREAT. */

#include <fcntl.h> /* |open| */
#include <stdio.h> /* |fprintf| */
#include <unistd.h> /* |read| */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int fd;
  if ((fd = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY)) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "open: %m\n");
    return 0;
  }

  char buf[8192];
  ssize_t n, m;

  while((n = read(0, buf, sizeof buf)) > 0) {
    m = write(fd, buf, n);
    if (m == -1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "write: %m\n");
      break;
    }
    if (m != n) {
      fprintf(stderr, "TODO: stuff all bytes in a loop\n");
      break;
    }
  }
  if (n == -1) fprintf(stderr, "read: %m\n");

  close(fd);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify at which time the device file should not exist. If you meant to ask, that the device file's existence should be checked against at the invocation of `program`, you can use the following in Bash:

```
[[ -f logfile ]] && program > devfile
```

An adapted version of @thatotherguy's comment that does basically the same by using `dd` instead of Bash internals looks like this:

```
program | dd conv=nocreat of=devfile
```

Comment: I need not execute `program` at all if `logfile` does not exist. (Incidentally, it is not log file, it is device file.) And I need to do this in one command to avoid race condition.

Comment: I adapted the answer to your comment.

Comment: thatotherguy's idea is great, but unfortunately it does not work with `busybox`'s `dd`: `dd: invalid argument 'nocreat' to 'conv'` (I edited OP to mention this.)

Answer (score 2):

Shells have options to *prevent* truncation, but not to *require* truncation.

To get FS level atomicity, you'd need to use an `open` syscall without `O_CREAT`. One way to do this in a script is to go through Python:

```
# Usage: nocreat filename cmd [args...]
nocreat() {
  python -c '
import os
import sys
fd=os.open(sys.argv[1], os.O_WRONLY | os.O_TRUNC)
os.dup2(fd,1)
os.close(fd)
os.execvp(sys.argv[2], sys.argv[2:])
    ' "$@"
}

# Equivalent to: echo "an example" > myfile
# Except it requires that the file already exists (atomically)
nocreat myfile echo "an example"
```

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, Busybox uses an `ash` shell by default, so you should be fine with POSIX.

When redirecting, you have the option to truncate (`>`) or append (`>>`), but nothing built in which will fail if a file does not exist. To achieve this in POSIX alone, you'd need some functionality through a pipe.

```
append_if_exists() {
  [ -f "$1" ] || return 1
  cat >> "$1"
}
```

You might use it like:

```
somecommand | append_if_exists /path/to/some.log
```

If the target file does not exist, the function returns immediately with an error, never having opened stdin, which should I believe should send a SIGPIPE back to `somecommand`, which should then terminate.

Note that there's a race here -- a file could be removed after the `[` but before the `cat` causing the redirect to create the file. But that comes with the territory, if you need something atomic, you may need to re-think this in an actual programming language.

Answer (score 1):

set the noclobber option, then bash will refuse to overwrite an existing file

```
$ set -C    # or set -o noclobber
$ touch foo
$ cat bar > foo
bash: foo: cannot overwrite existing file
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443595/bash-redirect-to-file-if-file-does-not-exist

Comment: This is the opposite of what the op wants. How does it help here?