# bash redirect write prevent create

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

Process A create a named pipe to receive command from script B. When A exit, it will delete the named pipe. the script write command to this pipe like this:

```
echo start > /run/command.fifo
```

but how to prevent script create a file named `/run/command.fifo` when the named pipe does not exists. add check before write is not safe:

```
[ -p /run/command.fifo ] || exit 1
echo start > /run/command.fifo
```

because the pipe may be deleted after check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53965873/how-to-redirect-output-to-file-not-creating-it-if-it-does-not-exist But honestly, this looks wrong - you should rather redirect a file descriptor to fifo and then deal with closing the file descriptor, not with file existence.

Comment: @KamilCuk probably you like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62344445/append-to-file-only-if-it-exists

Answer (score -1):

Then like this

```
[[ -p /run/command.fifo ]] && echo start > /run/command.fifo || echo 'fifo not exist'
```

Comment: Still not safe, no difference with my example script.

Comment: What's not safe here? Echo will start only if fifo exist.

Comment: Otherwise we can add some error message.

Comment: when echo excute, the fifo may has been deleted

Comment: there's a race here -- a pipe could be removed after the [ but before the echo